# My first row keeps repeating - <xsl:template match="Row">

Tags: 2010, list, xslt

I am getting data from a list with xsl and creating a nice print preview of that data.

The table I am creating is correct except my first row keeps repeating (it has the **column name** and it is only supposed to be at the top - appearing once and not above every row in the table).

My code looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Row"> 
    <div>
        <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Stability data</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong class="dalkur-title">Column name 1</strong></td>
      <td><strong class="dalkur-title">Column name 2</strong></td>
      <td><strong class="dalkur-title">Column name 3</strong></td>
      <td><strong class="dalkur-title">Column name 4</strong></td>
      <td><strong class="dalkur-title">Column name 5</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="text-offset"><xsl:value-of select="@x"/></span></td>
      <td><span class="text-offset"><xsl:value-of select="@XX"/></span></td>
      <td><span class="text-offset"><xsl:value-of select="@xxx"/></span></td>
      <td><span class="text-offset"><xsl:value-of select="@xxxx"/></span></td>
      <td><span class="text-offset"><xsl:value-of select="@xxxxx"/></span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
        </div>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is the code:

<xsl:template match="Row"> 
 <div>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Stability data</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong class="dalkur-title">column name1</strong></td>
      <td><strong class="dalkur-title">column name2</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td><span class="text-offset"><xsl:value-of select="@x"/></span></td>
<td><span class="text-offset"><xsl:value-of select="@xx"/></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div> 
</xsl:template>

Answer (score 0):

Keep your  i.e. header outside your template in template just repeat the rows. In above code what you are doing is repeating th for how many rows you have. 
Just try to create data view webpart and refer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following depending on the requirement

1. You can place the html header outside the template if it is static.
2. If the header is dynamic i.e if you are getting the value of the header from xsl you can place the header inside the following tags.

   ```
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">

    </xsl:if>
   ```